# What is the filename of last saved frame using saveFrame()

Tags: processing

In Processing, you can save a frame using `saveFrame('output-####.png')`. That will save the frame, name it `output-0001.png`, and place it in the sketch folder. The filename is always different because it follows a sequence, replacing the #### with the next number in the sequence.

However, saveFrame returns void. I wish it returned the String of the filename, but it doesn't.

How can I find out the name of the frame saved with `saveFrame(...)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always wrap that with a function to tell you the frameCount at that point:

```
void draw() {
  println(saveFrameAndGetFileName("output-####.png"));
}
String saveFrameAndGetFileName(String fileName) {
  saveFrame(fileName);
  String [] parts = fileName.split("####"); //getting pedantic here...
  return parts[0] + frameCount + parts[1];
}
```

or even more simply:

```
void draw() {
  saveFrame("output-####.png");
  println("output-" + frameCount + ".png");
}
```

EDIT: Fixed to give you the actual filename

Comment: I didn't know saveFrame() uses frameCount as the replacement for ####. I thought it was sequential. Thanks!