# Returning the filename of the current sketch

Tags: filesystems, processing

I am trying to write a GUI that will display the name of the sketch it was generated from using a simple `text()` command. However, I am running into trouble getting any of the general JS solutions to work for me. Many solutions I have found use the `filename` reserved word but that does not seem to be reserved in Processing 3.5.4. I have also tried parsing the strings using a similar method to what can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973272/what-is-the-filename-of-last-saved-frame-using-saveframe). I am *very* new to processing and this is only my 2nd attempt at using Processing.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path (as a string) to the sketch with `sketchPath()`.
From there you could either parse the string (pull off everything after the last slash) to get the sketch name, **or** you can use `sketchFile()` to get a reference to the file itself and get the name from there:

```
String path = sketchPath();
File file = sketchFile(path);
String sketchName = file.getName();

println(sketchName);
```

You could combine this all into one line like so:

```
String sketchName = sketchFile(sketchPath()).getName();
```